# getting @encode result from instance instead of the type in objective-c

Tags: objective-c-runtime

If you have a type:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *s;
@property (nonatomic) int i;
@end
...
Foo *instance = [[Foo alloc] init];
```

So, of course, you can get the type encoding:

```
@encode(Foo);  // {<class>=#<encoded ivars>}
```

But, what if you have the instance?  Like:

```
@encode(instance);  // Obviously, not a valid call.
```

It doesn't seem all that hard to do it with the runtime: You can get the class from the instance, and name and the ivars from the class, and you can get the type encoding from the ivars.  So, isn't there some way to do this?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@encode()` is a compile-time directive. `@encode(instance)` is invalid because `@encode()` operates on types. You could do `@encode(typeof(instance))` but that would return "@" because `instance` is an object pointer type. You could also do `@encode(typeof(*instance))` which will give you the encoding of the class that `instance` is **declared** to point to (which may differ from the class of object that it actually points to at runtime).

This distinction between declared and actual type is, of course, crucial. There's no way a compile-time directive can anticipate what the actual type will be at runtime.

It's also not clear, for any given use of `@encode()`, which type you would actually be interested in. If you want the runtime type, use the runtime functions to construct it yourself, as you suggest. If you want the static type, well, you have the type name right there in your code, so just put that into the `@encode()` directive. (You could use the `typeof` operator as I showed before, but that just introduces a layer of indirection that's not really helpful. You'll get the same type as is used in the declaration of `instance`.)

I should say, there are *very* few good reasons to use `@encode()`. You're probably a lot better of rethinking your use of it, anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  encode gives the same type encoding for primitives that you get with ivar_getTypeEncoding, so I started down this road.  But, it's quite different with classes, so your suggestion to just avoid it seems like the solution.